# How to get rid of default font (Helvetica Neue) in Numbers?

Tags: font, numbers, template

I am using Numbers '09. I defined (and saved within `My Templates`) a template of a very basic table format where all cells are formatted with Palatino:

[image: My_Templates]

If I simply hit <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>within any selected cell,
immediatly the font of the cell is switched to Helvetica Neue:

[image: My_Templates after ⌘+X]

This magic font switching also occurs on some other operations (example: move of a block of cells).
This is leaving cells with the wrong format. When I discover this format corruption I have to manually set the font back to the one I configured in My Templates.

What could I have done wrong with my template?
How may I avoid this behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

You need to update the table style so that your changes persist for new cells. Make the changes to the formatting of the table as you wish, then select the dropdown triangle for the currently selected table style and choose **Redefine Style from Table** (Numbers '09).

[image]

---

In more recent versions of Numbers, simply click the blue **Update** button for the Table Style. The asterisk indicates changes have been made to the currently selected cell which has not been saved to the style.

[image]

Comment: Clear, applied and fixed. Thank you. I suggest you to add at the end of the 1st scenaio (the one which worked for me): •• return •• Then save this as template with `File > Save as Template...` to fix your original template which contained a wrong table style.